# Grab all but one element in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a `pandas` `Series` that has many values indexed by strings.  I want to grab all of them except for one.

```
my_series.ix['intercept'] #<--- this has the value I don't want
```

Is there a way to grab everything in `my_series` except for what is returned by `my_series.ix['intercept']`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could construct a `mask` -- a boolean array which is True where the Series index equals the particular value:

```
mask = my_series.index.isin(['intercept'])
```

Then you could select the remaining rows in the typical fashion:

```
my_series.loc[~mask]
```

---

Note that if the value occurs in the index more than once, then all rows with the same index will be removed:

```
my_series = pd.Series([10,20,30,40], index=['foo','intercept','baz','intercept'])
# foo          10
# intercept    20
# baz          30
# intercept    40
# dtype: int64

mask = my_series.index.isin(['intercept'])
print(my_series.loc[~mask])
```

yields

```
foo    10
baz    30
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Quick clarification on this question, would this remove indexes that are super sets or subsets of that string literal?  For example would it remove entries where the index is 'int' or entries where the index is 'intercept_1'?  For my current particular case it won't matter so I'm just asking this follow up out of curiosity

Comment: No, it wouldn't. (I encourage you to try it though; that's the best way to learn.) Remember that the index could contain values other than strings, so `isin` is just checking for membership (equality) and not doing anything string-specific like checking if one string is contained in another string.